# Why is this element moving?

Tags: html, css

I have an entry form on my website and after you click submit it moves in google chrome but not in firefox or ie.  Is there a way to make it stationary in chrome also?  I've tried so many different things I forget everything that's been tried before now.

The web address is http://www.readysetpixel.net/contest.html

Let me know if you can't duplicate the issue.

UPDATE:

Uninstalled chrome - deleted history and fixed reg with ccleaner - reinstalled chrome

Still having the same issue --- when clicking submit all of the content slides up 20px

Fixed:  Set a height on the FORM itself and is no longer sliding the whole thing up.

Comment: Behaves the same way for me in both firefox and chrome (and even in IE!!!!11!)

Comment: Nothing is moving not in Chrome, nor in Firefox. Maybe on small screens, a scrollbar is being shown, which shrinks the content a little bit.
Which of the elements is moving? Which version of Chrome do you use?

Comment: 21.0.1180.79 m  and the submit button slides up like 20px when i click on it

Comment: and why would someone -1 me for trying to figure out a problem?

Comment: It may be a plugin or some other sort of browser extension that is causing this on your system.

Comment: Alright I will reinstall chrome and see if that fixes it

Comment: @AnthonyRusso I'm just guessing, but posting what you have tried would help.

Comment: I have tried so many different things it would be ridiculous amount to post.  I've changed other elements and itself.  I just uninstalled chrome and re-installed.  cleared my history using ccleaner and also the registry files... still doing the same thing.  When I click on submit the button and everything else slides up about 20px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: Set a height on the FORM itself and is no longer sliding the whole thing up.

Answer (score 1):

onClick there is a loading icon that appears to the top left of the submit button. That causes the rest of your content above it to shift up.

Answer (score 0):

You have auto height, maybe you should try forcing a fixed height.

```
.content {
width: 800px;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it leaves a gap at the bottom with that method.

Answer (score 0):

I set a breakpoint and single-stepped your .submit() handler, and it looks like this line is causing the jump:

```
$('#load').append('<center><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Currently Loading" id="loading" /></center>').delay('500');
```

Comment: actually I altered that and the submit button still slides up.  i set a form heiht and it is now working with the original code.